# Implementing AWS(Amazon Web Services) in Android Application

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I have a task to implement in my Android Application. I have a `.xls` sheet which I have to access in my Android Application using AWS. I am totally new to AWS.
Can any body tell me from where I can start. Where I have to store this .xls file. Definitely I can't store in local Memory. I have to store it on cloud.
But I am not getting the idea for achieving my requirement. Is there anyone who implemented it before who can give me a direction.
Waiting for responses.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the Java AWS SDK
http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

For simple storage you probably what to check out the S3 file system
http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any example to do that.

Comment: Check here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also an Android AWS SDK if you do not want to implement a server.  http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/ .  I'd suggest looking into using the TransferManager (available for both Java and Android depending on what you end up going with).  For Android there is a specific guide on uploading files to S3 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html